# Android addTextChangedListener not fired when EditText Invisible

Tags: android

I am building a PIN entry screen that has an invisible EditText to collect the PIN and four ImageViews that I populate as the user enters the PIN.  It all works fine when the EditText is visible but when I make it invisible the addTextChangedListener does not fire?

XML

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/pinEntryEditText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:maxLength="4"
    android:inputType="numberPassword"/>
```

Code

```
mPinEntryEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            switch (s.length()) {
                case 1:
                    setPinFieldColor(mPinOneImageView, R.color.white);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    setPinFieldColor(mPinTwoImageView, R.color.white);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    setPinFieldColor(mPinThreeImageView, R.color.white);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    setPinFieldColor(mPinFourImageView, R.color.white);
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you don't want to have the `EditText` be visible since you want the input to go straight to the ImageViews.

Can I maybe recommend an external library like https://github.com/alphamu/PinEntryEditText?

--

If you want to make a homegrown solution, maybe you can just show the keyboard and listen for keyboard input with `onKeyDown`?

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    //Logic...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be intentional behavior.

The [TextView source](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java) (EditText extends TextView) overrides `onVisibilityChanged()`:

```
@Override
protected void onVisibilityChanged(View changedView, int visibility) {
    super.onVisibilityChanged(changedView, visibility);
    if (mEditor != null && visibility != VISIBLE) {
        mEditor.hideCursorAndSpanControllers();
        stopTextActionMode();
    }
}
```

As you can see, if the visibility of the View isn't VISIBLE, `stopTextActionMode()` will be called, which basically stops all updates to the View. This is probably to save on resources, since, usually, when a View is invisible, you don't need to be listening for changes in its state.

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem like you can override this behavior, although I don't really see why you need to receive updates from an invisible text input.